# how to display the data in a column with sql and php

Tags: php

i have table in sql like this :

```
----------------------------------
| id | name      | time1 | time2 |
----------------------------------
| 1  | softball  | 05.00 | 10.00 | 
| 2  | softball  | 10.00 | 11.00 |
| 3  | softball  | 11.00 | 14.00 |
-----------------------------------
```

here is my code :

```
$query = "select * from schejule";
$sql = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table class='table table-striped table-advance table-hover'>";
while ($u = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "<tr><td>$u[time1] - $u[time2]</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

but if i create like that, will display it like this :

```
-----------------
| 05.00 - 10.00 |
-----------------
| 10.00 - 11.00 |
----------------- 
| 11.00 - 14.00 |
-----------------
```

i want to display it with php like this :

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| days | 05.00 - 10.00 | 10.00 - 11.00 | 11.00 - 14.00 |
--------------------------------------------------------
| mo   |               |               |               |
--------------------------------------------------------
| tu   |               |               |               |
--------------------------------------------------------
| we   |               |               |               |
--------------------------------------------------------
| th   |               |               |               |
--------------------------------------------------------
| fr   |               |               |               |
--------------------------------------------------------
| sa   |               |               |               |
--------------------------------------------------------
| su   |               |               |               |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

How can i display like that if i use php. I only know how to make it in rows.
Thx..

Comment: Where you define days in your sql table?

Comment: Does the table have dynamic number of columns? What do you want to fill in each row for each timeslot?  (e.g.: the `mo` row of each timeslot)

Comment: Amy  : made by manual <br>
Cyhoi: yes, and i want to fill it with 'rent'

Comment: Where does "rent" come from? or it's just a constant string?

Comment: yes just constant string. i want display table like that..

Answer (score 0):

Try to prepare each column of a row before printing it to output stream.

Sample code for the first row (not tested):

```
$query = "select * from schejule";
$sql = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table class='table table-striped table-advance table-hover'>";
$row = '<tr><td>days</td>';
while ($u = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $row .= "<td>$u[time1] - $u[time2]</td>";
}
$row .= '</tr>';
echo $row;
echo "</table>";
```